# somthing wrong in ajax api and laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

hey i have some error in my api request 419 when i submit the form its show in console this error
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)**

i tried the url in another projects with the same code its show nothing in the console and works fine

this is my logic login:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { authLogin } from "../../redux/actions/auth/ActionAuth";

const LoginLogic = () => {
  const myDispatch = useDispatch();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("12");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("123456");

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

  // selector
  const responseAuthLogin = useSelector((state) => state.rootAuth.login);

  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handelUsername = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  };
  const handelPassword = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);
    setLoad(true);
    await myDispatch(
      authLogin({
        "student_id": username,
        "password": password,
      })
    );
    setLoad(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (load === false) {
      if (responseAuthLogin) {
        console.log(responseAuthLogin);
      }
    }
  }, [load]);

  return [username, password, handelUsername, handelPassword, submitLogin];
};

export default LoginLogic;
```

this is my action code:

```
import baseUrl from "../api/BaseUrl";

export const UseCreateData = async (apiUrl, param) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      // Accept: "application/json",
      // "Content-Type": "application/json",
      // Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await baseUrl.post(apiUrl, param, config);
  return response;
};
```

i tried to add some headers and nothing work and tried to allow all cockies and nothing work for me

Comment: Probably you forgot add CSRF token to form data.

Answer (score 0):

419 error code is because you are missing CSRF token in your call.